# ASP.NET MVC: First parameter in action method is always empty when form is submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem when passing values to Controller action method.

I have a route map like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "VehicleAdvancedSearchResult",
   url: "search-result/{searchTypeSlug}/{condition}/{makeSlug}/{modelName}/{modelExt}/{categorySlug}/{parishSlug}/{yearRange}/{priceRange}",
   defaults: new
      {
         controller = "SearchResult",
         action = "VehicleAdvanceSearch",
         //SearchTypeSlug = UrlParameter.Optional
         //Condition = UrlParameter.Optional,
         //MakeSlug = UrlParameter.Optional,
         //ModelName = UrlParameter.Optional,
         //ModelExt = UrlParameter.Optional,
         //CategorySlug = UrlParameter.Optional,
         //ParishSlug = UrlParameter.Optional,
         //YearRange = UrlParameter.Optional,
         //PriceRange = UrlParameter.Optional
      }
   );
```

I tried with `UrlParameter.Optional` but it did not work.

In the View I have a form with no `action` defined by default but when I hit submit the action attribute is added to it with correct values.

[image: action attribute is added to form with correct values and pattern]

The problem is the first parameter value is always coming as empty string when the controller method is actually called.

[image: Debug result]

What I am doing wrong?

The other issue is I want the action method to be called even if the URL is partially complete or even it has no parameter. In my case if I type in just `http://locahots:55904/search-result/` or `http://locahots:55904/search-result/for-sale/`, meaning as long as it is partial, I am always ending up with a 404. But I want them to redirect to another page if it is a partial URL.

I have already done that check in my action method but the method is not at all being called with a partial URL.

This is required because Google crawls the URL with every single folder structure separately to index them.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

For controller method if you want to partially call you need to defined optional parameters in method

For example,

```
Public ActionResult <method name>(string param1="",string param2=""){}
```

Now if you want to call method with partial arguments you need to pass argument right to left.

Or an alternative way is you can override method with different arguments option you have.

Answer (score 0):

For this action method to be called by partial url, you can create a new route in RouteConfig file having different route name pointing to the same action method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "VehicleAdvancedSearchResult_V2",
   url: "search-result/{parameterName?}",
  defaults: new
  {
     controller = "SearchResult",
     action = "VehicleAdvanceSearch",
   }
  );
```

Second way is that you can apply Attribute Routing on this action using the Route Attribute. 
For Example:

```
 [Route("[action]/{parameterName?}")] //?--> for optional parameter
 public ActionResult VehicleAdvanceSearch()
```

In Order to resolve the issue of First Parameter null, you can create a Model for all the parameters and then hit the controller action with Modal as parameter. 
For Example:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult VehicleAdvanceSearch(SearchResultModel model){}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting! I will give it a try and get back to you. Thank you for your input :)